# Error: Request failed with status code 404 in ASP.NET Core with Vue.js

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core

Only a button and scripts are in the `index.cshtmp` page. In my main.Js, I have a method called getItems() for retrieving all the items. I used Vue.js and Axios for that. I called `getItems` methods inside a `Admincontroller`.It is a GET request. But it gives me that console error  `Error: Request failed with status code 404`. I add a brake point in the Admin controller, But my request does not go inside the controller. Please help me to fix this.Thank you

```
**index.cshtml**
<div id="app">

    <button v-on:click="getItems">Get Items</button>

</div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/Admin/main.js"></script>

}
```

**main.js**

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        price: 0,
        showPrice:true,
        loading: false
    },
    methods: {
        getItems() {
            this.loading = true;
            axios.get('/Admin/Items')
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                })
                .catch(err =>{
                console.log(err);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                })

        }

    }
});
```

**AdminController**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PracticalTest.Application.Admin;
using PracticalTest.Database;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PracticalTest.UIs.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _ctx;
        public AdminController(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        [HttpGet("Items")]
        public IActionResult GetItems() =>Ok( new GetItems(_ctx).Do());

        [HttpPost("Items")]
        public IActionResult CreateItem(CreateItem.ItemViewModel vm) =>Ok( new CreateItem(_ctx).Do(vm));

        [HttpDelete("Items/{id}")] 
        public IActionResult DeleteItem(int id) =>Ok( new DeleteItem(_ctx).Do(id));

        [HttpPut("Items")]
        public IActionResult UpdateItem(UpdateItem.ItemViewModel vm) =>Ok( new UpdateItem(_ctx).Do(vm));
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using postman to test your API and help isolate the issue?

Comment: Are we able to see the startup file for the c# project?

Comment: @MichaelLeipper I test using postman. but same issue. What changes should do to the startup file?

Comment: I was hoping that you would place your startup.cs file in here.

Comment: When you run the query in postman what URL are you using?

Comment: I was hoping to see the following in your startup :
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

Answer (score 0):

> I called getItems methods inside a Admincontroller.It is a GET request. But it gives me that console error  Error: Request failed with status code 404. I add a brake point in the Admin controller, But my request does not go inside the controller.

If [you mix Razor pages and  MVC (or APIs) in same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876401/how-to-redirect-controller-to-razor-page-in-asp-net-core), please make sure you register required service(s), and required middleware(s) are added.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddControllers();

    //if mix MVC feature, need regiester this service
    //services.AddControllersWithViews();

    //...
    //other sevices you need
    //...
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    //other required middleware(s) here
    //...

    app.UseRouting();

    //...

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();

        endpoints.MapControllers();

        //endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        //    name: "default",
        //    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```