# How to Redirect Controller to razor page in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I send data from `Index.cshtml` to my controller. Then I want to redirect from the controller to the `index.cshtml` page inside the `Admin` folder (those two are two different `index.cstml` files). I added a screenshot of the file hierarchy. Please help me to solve this.

I tried this, but it's not working

```
public IActionResult Login([FromBody] Users user)
{
    if (user.UserName.Equals("admin") & user.Password.Equals("admin"))
    {
        return LocalRedirect("/Admin/Index"); // redirect to index page in Admin folder
    }
    else
        return RedirectToPage("Error");
}
```

Folder structure:

[image: folder structure for better understand]

This is startup page

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using PracticalTest.Database;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace PracticalTest.UIs
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["defaultConnection"]));
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

        }
    }
}
```

AdminController

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PracticalTest.Application.Admin;
using PracticalTest.Database;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PracticalTest.UIs.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _ctx;
        public AdminController(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        [HttpGet("Items")]
        public IActionResult GetItems() =>Ok( new GetItems(_ctx).Do());
        [HttpGet("Users")]
        public IActionResult GetUsers() => Ok(new GetUsers(_ctx).Do());

        [HttpGet("Items/{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetItem(int id) =>Ok(new GetItem(_ctx).Do(id));


        [HttpGet("Users/{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetUser(int id) => Ok(new GetUser(_ctx).Do(id));

        [HttpPost("Items")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateItem([FromBody]CreateItem.Requst requst) =>Ok((await new CreateItem(_ctx).Do(requst)));
        [HttpPost("Users")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser([FromBody] CreateUser.Requst requst) => Ok((await new CreateUser(_ctx).Do(requst)));

        [HttpDelete("Items/{id}")] 
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteItem(int id) =>Ok((await new DeleteItem(_ctx).Do(id)));

        [HttpDelete("Users/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUser(int id) => Ok((await new DeleteUser(_ctx).Do(id)));

        [HttpPut("Items")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateItem([FromBody]UpdateItem.Request rq) =>Ok((await new UpdateItem(_ctx).Do(rq)));
        [HttpPut("Users")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser([FromBody] UpdateUser.Request rq) => Ok((await new UpdateUser(_ctx).Do(rq)));

       
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Thamra Devps, I have tested your code and works well. What is your error? Or where did your page redirect to? Please also share what is your Startup.cs about configuring routing.

Comment: Not redirecting. I've shared the startup page. @Rena

Comment: Hi @Thamra Devps, I know you do not redirect, but it must have a wrong redirect or makes error. It is not possible just did nothing.   Also , you use `endpoints.MapControllers();` in your Startup.cs so your controller need add `Route` attribute to specific the route.  And did your AdminController contains Index action?  More details will be helpful to your issue.

Comment: hi, @Rena I add AdminController now. Please help me to solve this.I'm a fresh developer to asp.net

Comment: Hi @Thamra Devps, your AdminController is correct without any conflict with `/Admin/Index`.  Could you please share your Index page and simple backend which is in Admin folder? And please check your project if any other backend url is :`Admin/Index`. Besides, do you try to use `RedirectToPage("/Admin/Index")`? Actually, I suggest you can debug your code and check what is the error, if it does not redirect, it must makes error. You can check the `Output` panel to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if (user.UserName.Equals("admin") & user.Password.Equals("admin"))
{
    // redirect to index page in Admin folder
    return RedirectToPage("Admin/Index"); 
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to an action, you would pass the action as the first argument and the controller as the second argument.

```
RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
```

If you just want to redirect to the page itself, you would go to the directory that the view is located. Such as return View("~/Views/Chats/Index.cshtml");

```
return View("~/Views/Admin/Index.cshtml");
```

In the code above you would replace the argument with wherever your page is located.